# How to print out calendar.month_name array in python?

Tags: python, arrays

I have the following code:

```
import calendar
month=calendar.month_name   
print(month)
```

I wish to have following output which is in array form or list form:

`['January','February',...,'December']`

but above code return me nothing.

Anyone can point out my error?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What it returns is actually an [array object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html#calendar.month_name). If you want to convert it to a list, call [`list()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-list) on it:

```
>>> import calendar
>>> calendar.month_name
<calendar._localized_month instance at 0x10e0b2830>
>>> list(calendar.month_name)
['', 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
```

By default the list has the empty string as its first element so that indexing may be done from 1 and not 0. If you want to remove this while still converting it to a list, just call `calendar.month_name[1:]`

---

Depending on your code, there might not actually need to be any reason to do this. The array object will have the same properties as any list:

```
>>> for month in calendar.month_name[1:]:
...     print month
... 
January
February
March
April
May
June
July
August
September
October
November
December
```

Comment: if you're looking to remove the 0th index, then you would only need `cal.month_name[1:]`, making the list() call redundant in `list(calendar.month_name[1:])`

Answer (score 2):

```
>>>import calendar
>>>months = [x for x in calendar.month_name if x]
>>>print(months)
['January',
 'February',
 'March',
 'April',
 'May',
 'June',
 'July',
 'August',
 'September',
 'October',
 'November',
 'December']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **filter** to get non-empty strings:

```
import calendar
months = filter(None, calendar.month_name)
```